# How to Force NON-SSL for certain URL (.htacces)

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

How to Force NON-SSL for one file ? in this case:

Entire site run on HTTPS
I need to run on HTTP just one file in this exact structure:
https://sitename.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/FileName.php?....string....

I have created one .htacces on the "folder3" but,... don`t work

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force non-SSL for certain URL's
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteRule ^https\:\/\/sitename\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/folder3\/FileName\.php\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/sitename\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/folder3\/FileName\.php\/?\/$1" [R=301,L,QSA]

Deny From All
<FilesMatch "^FileName\.php$">
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

Example URL: https://pepecine.online/plugins/streaming/plugin/online.php?http://powvideo.net/yh24veoqgiop

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: Becouse this page (filename.php) will load an iframe from differents external sites. Of corse, not all this external sites are served over https, for example: https://pepecine.online/plugins/streaming/plugin/online.php?http://powvideo.net/yh24veoqgiop

Comment: The page given in the query of the example link works perfectly well with https: https://pepecine.online/plugins/streaming/plugin/online.php?https://powvideo.net/yh24veoqgiop

Comment: Yes, if you change from http to https will work, but others external pages dont accept https - for example - http://pepecine.net/plugins/streaming/plugin/online.php?https://streamcloud.eu/0psd4w9dpium